# Error con variable en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo un programa con una foto en Tkinter pero, cunado la ejecuto me da este error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/programa1/programa_empleados.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/programa1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\programa1\programa_empleados.py", line 15, in <module>
    venta=Image.open(pathToImage)

NameError: name 'pathToImage' is not defined
```

Si entendí bien el error quiere decir que `pathToImage` no esta definida, he intentado buscar en internet pero no he encontrado respuestas a mi problema. Si alguien sabe como ayudarme lo agradecería mucho.

Aquí mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("softnum_empleados")

ventana.geometry('900x800')

boton1=Button(ventana, text="VENTA")

boton1.grid(column=10, row=9)

venta=Image.open(pathToImage)
ph=ImageTk.PhotoImage(venta)

if os.path.isfile(pathToImage):
     print ('image exists')
     
else:   
     print ('image does not exits')


fondo1=Label(ventana, image=ph)
fondo1.image=ph 
fondo1.grid(column=7, row=10)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si me puedo permitir darte un consejo: Parece que tienes lagunas en conceptos fundamentales de la programación. Quizás sería mejor que dieras un paso atrás y dejaras Tkinter para cuando hayas consolidado un poco más tus conocimientos de programación básica.

Answer (score 2):

El error es auto explicativo, te está diciendo que no has asignado ningún valor a la variable `pathToImage`. Antes de intentar utilizarla en tu código debes asignarle un valor.

En otras palabras, antes de la linea:

```
venta=Image.open(pathToImage)
```

Deberías añadir algo como esto:

```
pathToImage = "c:/path/to/my/image/"
```

Pero por razones de compatibilidad a través de sistemas ya que de un sistema a otro cambia la dirección de los slash de `/` a `\` te recomiendo utilizar `os.path` de la siguiente manera:

```
pathToImage = os.path('c:','path','to','my','image')
```